# Why some method returns undefined in React hooks and not in React classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello I am new in react and I am building a restaurant app so I am facing a problem which comes when I transformed my react class application to react hooks, why is this not working well in React hooks If in React classes It does

```
const RenderDish = (props) => {
const dish = props.dish;

if (dish != null) {
    return (
        <Card
            featuredTitle={dish.name}
            image={require('./images/uthappizza.png')}
            >
            <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                {dish.description}
            </Text>
            <Icon 
                raised
                reverse 
                name={ props.favorite ? 'heart' : 'heart-o' }
                type='font-awesome'
                color='#f50'
                onPress={() => props.favorite ? console.log('Already favorite') : props.onPress()}
            />
        </Card>
    );
}
else {
    return(
        <View></View>
    )
}}


const Dishdetail = (props) => {

const [dishes, setDishes] = useState(DISHES);
const [comments, setComments] = useState(COMMENTS);
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([])

const markFavorite = (dishId) => setFavorites({ favorites: favorites.concat(dishId) })

const dishId = props.route.params.dishId;

return (
    <ScrollView>
        <RenderDish dish={dishes[+dishId]} 
            favorite={favorites.some(el => el === dishId)}
            onPress={() => markFavorite(dishId)}
            />
        <RenderComments comments={comments.filter(comment => comment.dishId === dishId)} />
    </ScrollView>
);}
```

This is the error syntax

> TypeError: favorites.some is not a funcion, (In 'favorites.some(function (el) { return el === dishId; }),'favorites.some' is undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mismatched types: you are setting an object here:
`setFavorites({ favorites: favorites.concat(dishId) })` and then trying to accessing the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) array method here: `favorites.some(el => el === dishId)`

Update to set an array:

```
setFavorites(favorites.concat(dishId));
```

Comment: Omg It is true, Thank you very much Samuel, I did not see it. It will not happen anymore